# How to prevent click event triggering for last li?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, html-lists

```
<ul>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
</ul>
```

I need to prevent click event for last li element. I tried like below,

```
$(document).on("click", "ul li:not(last-child)", function (e) {
//do something
}
```

But this is not working. Post your answers if came across the same.

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also achieve this by `li:not(:last)`

```js
$(document).on("click", "ul li:not(:last)", function (e) {
   alert()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5):

It should be [`:last-child`](https://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/) instead of `last-child` in the selector string.

```
$(document).on("click", "ul li:not(:last-child)", function (e) {
   //do something
})
```

```js
$(document).on("click", "ul li:not(:last-child)", function (e) {
console.log('clicked');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
</ul>
```

---

Although [event-delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) is only necessary if the elements are dynamically generated other ways bind handler directly.

```
$("ul li:not(:last-child)").on("click", function (e) {
   //do something
})
```

```js
$("ul li:not(:last-child)").on("click", function(e) {
  console.log('clicked');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
</ul>
```

---

To avoid selecting nested `li` use [direct child selector(`>`)](https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/).

```
$("ul > li:not(:last-child)").on("click", function (e) {
   //do something
})
```

```js
$("ul > li:not(:last-child)").on("click", function (e) {
  console.log('clicked');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It is triggering now also $(document).on("click", ".ul li:not(:last-child), ul.active", function (e) { } :( :(

Comment: @DAon :  where is `, ul.active`?

Comment: @DAon :  all of them are working as expected... you can check the snippet